# Quoting book at different pages

Tags: biblatex, multiple-citations

Seems like a basic question, but I did not come across an example. If I want to cite pages from a book (pp. 30-35) and on a different point in my text I want to cite FROM THE SAME BOOK a different part (pp. 60-70), how do I do this with biblatex? Do I need two different entries? How do I show which pages I mean in my text if I would only use one entry in the bibliograpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two passages your want to cite are from the same bona fide *book* the usual way is not to give any page numbers in the `.bib` entry and the bibliography, but to instead give the page reference directly in the citation with the optional argument of `\cite`.

```
Lorem \autocite[45-47]{worman}
ipsum \autocite[60-62]{worman}
```

If you refer to different chapters/papers in an edited volume (i.e. to works written by different authors that just happen to be in the same collecting volume), it is more common to have two different entries, one for each chapter/paper.

The first case of a bona fide book is the `@book` entry `worman` below. The example of two papers from the same collection work uses `@incollection` and is demonstrated with `gaonkar:in` and `povinelli`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  subtitle     = {Style in {Greek} Literature},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}
@collection{gaonkar,
  editor       = {Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar},
  title        = {Alternative Modernities},
  date         = 2001,
  publisher    = {Duke University Press},
  location     = {Durham and London},
  isbn         = {0-822-32714-7},
}
@incollection{gaonkar:in,
  author       = {Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar},
  title        = {On Alternative Modernities},
  pages        = {1-23},
  crossref     = {gaonkar},
}
@incollection{povinelli,
  author       = {Elizabeth A. Povinelli},
  title        = {Settler Modernity and the Quest for an Indigenous Tradition},
  pages        = {24-57},
  crossref     = {gaonkar},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[45-47]{worman}
ipsum \autocite[60-62]{worman}
dolor \autocite[18-19]{gaonkar:in}
dolor \autocite[26]{povinelli}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Worman 2002, pp. 45–47) ipsum (Worman 2002, pp. 60–62) dolor (Gaonkar 2001b, pp. 18–19) dolor (Povinelli 2001, p. 26)]

Answer (score 2):

Using APA style only one entry in the database is enough.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[style=apa,
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
language=american]
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname41.bib}
    @article{greenwade93,
    author  = {George Greenwade},
    title   = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
    year    = {1993},
    journal = {TUGBoat},
    volume  = {14},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {342--351},
    }
    
    
    @bookininproceedings{aristotle2012,
    author = {Aristotle},
    bookineditor = {Book Editor}, 
    title = {The Ancient Text},
    crossref = {Onyme2012},
    pages = {1-555},
    }   


\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname41.bib}

\begin{document}

Start  reading  \citep[p. 344]{greenwade93} and continue with  \citep[pp, 199--202]{aristotle2012} and  \citep[pp 100--102]{aristotle2012}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: one]

Comment: This would look a bit nicer if the space after `'p.` in the Greenwade reference wasn't so wide.  The way to avoid this is to put a backslash after the period: `p.\ 344`.   This is the standard TeX way of indicating that a period after a lowercase letter (as in an abbreviation) isn't the end of a sentence.

Comment: With `biblatex` the prefix 'p.' or 'pp.' will be inserted automatically if appropriate, so `\citep[p. 344]{greenwade93}` should ideally be just `\citep[344]{greenwade93}` (and similarly for the other citations). The example `.bib` entry misses the entry `Onyme2012`, which is referenced by `aristotle2012`. The last `}` in the `.bib` file doesn't match any other opening curly brace. It might also be worth mentioning that the same general principle applies for all styles and not just for the very specific APA style you get with `style=apa,`.